# Perl/Java Byte Encoding Differences

Tags: java, perl, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

So right now, my Java code is creating a different SHA-256 hash than our Perl code, but only when UTF8 characters come into play. I did some debugging and found the byte[] representation of the name Jörg is as follows in the languages:

Java 74, -61, -74, 114, 103

Perl 74, 195, 182, 114, 103

Could be causing the difference in the hashes? It appears Java uses signed bytes, while Perl uses unsigned. Further information if needed/requested!

Thanks!

Comment: *"It appears Java uses signed bytes, while Perl uses unsigned."* -- you answered your own question right there. Use `theByte & 0xFF` to get an unsigned version as an int.

Comment: But, does it cause a difference when I use MessageDigest (SHA-256) to hash the String?

Comment: Just curious, when you say "my Java code is creating" do you mean you wrote your own implementation of the hashing?

Comment: Convert to `unsigned byte[]`.

Comment: We found the problem. Ended up having nothing to do with signed/unsigned issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So the issue turned out to be that in Java, when I was reversing the String it was reversing the characters (as expected). In Perl, reverse actually works on the bytes. This means that Jörg when reversed looked like this in the languages:

Java 103 114 -61 -74 74

Perl 103 114 195 182 74

Hope this helps somebody else out!

Comment: Sounds like you weren't decoding the byte string into characters as the data entered your program. See "perldoc perlunicode" (http://perldoc.perl.org/perlunicode.html) for details.